# Does it make sense to access a connection on a type from a mutation in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, github-api

I'm fairly new to using GraphQL but I'm trying to figure out how pagination on a mutation would look like. Does it even make sense to do so?

For example, taking a look at the `updateProjectV2ItemPosition` mutation on Github https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#updateprojectv2itemposition

There is a return field `items` which is a connection and looks like it supports pagination with a cursor. For arguments sake, lets say there is 20 and I want to get them in batches of 5.

So I make my first call and get my cursor back, but then when I make the call again to retrieve the next 5, wouldn't the mutation try to execute again? In this scenario it is not too big a deal because each subsequent mutation execution isn't going to change anything, but what if this mutation did something like adding a comment? Wouldn't we add a new comment every time we try to get the next batch of whatever it is we are paginating over?

This question isn't unique to Github and I'm actually trying to build my own API and have been looking at big corporations APIs to base mine off of and this is just puzzling to me.